# What css can I use to get a fieldset to adjust to a mobile device?

Tags: html, css, mobile, kendo-ui, kendo-window

I have a ASP MVC project using Razor and Telerik Kendo controls.  I have a view I'm trying to adjust to a mobile device.  Everything is working except one fieldset control.  I've stripped down the code to just the fieldset and can't figure out the problem.  The non-mobile version of the view had a Kendo Window on it.  If I keep the code for this window, the fieldset adjusts it's width to fit on a mobile device.  However, if I remove the code for the window, the fieldset does not adjust it's width.  I've tried adjusting the width of the fieldset, adjusting divs around the fieldset, trying to add other controls like divs and spans (with and without the width set) in place of the window, but nothing works.  It only work if the window control is on the page.  What is causing this?  How do I get the fieldset to adjust it's width to a mobile device?

Here is my code:

```html
@*@(Html.Kendo().Window()
        .Name("rptWin")
        .Visible(false)
        .Width(750)
        .Height(700)
        .Draggable()
        .Resizable()
        .Title("Invoice")
.Actions(actions => actions.Pin().Refresh().Maximize().Close())
.LoadContentFrom("WoRptWorkOrder", "WorkOrder", new { pWoid = ViewBag.CurrId })
)*@

@using (Html.BeginForm("WoAdminEdit", "WorkOrder"))
{
    <div style="font-size: 10px">
        <fieldset style="padding: 0 10px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #666;
        border-radius: 8px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #666;">
</fieldset>
    </div>
    Html.EndForm();
}
```

If the window control is commented out, the fieldset on the right side extends off the page:

[image]

However, if I uncomment the Kendo Window, it works:

[image]

This is what I want, but I don't want the Kendo Window in the code.  The window is not being used or called, as far as I can tell.  I've stripped out all other HTML and javascript. I can't figure out why the Kendo Window is affecting the fieldset and I can't figure any way to adjust the fieldset's width if the Kendo Window is removed.  I'm perplexed at what's going on.  Can anyone help?

*** Update 1 ***

Here is the HTML without the Kendo Window:
[image]

And with the Kendo Window:
[image]

I also tried setting the width of the div, the fieldset, the html tag, and the body tag.  I won't include examples from all of them, but basically without the Kendo Window on the page, a wider area is shown making the fieldset and the text in it too small to read on a mobile device.  Both of these are with the div set to 300px and in Chrome with an iPhone emulator.  Otherwise the only difference is the presence of the Kendo Window on the page.

With the Kendo Window, appears "zoomed in":

[image]

Without the Kendo Window, shows a wider view:

[image]

Again, I want it to look the way it does with the Kendo window on the page, but since I'm not using the Kendo window I'd like to remove the control.  I need to know how to duplicate the results without having an unused control on the page.  Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to post the resulting HTML rather than the Kendo code? It looks like there's something in there which gives the body or the form a fixed width that is larger than the viewport.

Comment: That said, you could try giving the fieldset a width in `vw`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've posted my HTML.  Having the Kendo control on the page does add a lot to the HTML.  Nothing sticks out to me as setting the page size, but I'll keep looking.  Would appreciate it if you notice anything that I could change.  I'm not sure what you mean by "vw".  I've tried setting the width of the fieldset, the div around it, the html block, and the form.  If I remove the Kendo Window, I get a wider view which is unreadable on a mobile device.  I posted some screenshots.  Do you have any idea what the Kendo code is doing to make the page appear "zoomed in"?

Comment: `vw` is a css unit, 1/100 of the width of the viewport, so `100vw` is the whole width. By the way, screenshots of code are no good. We need a [mcve].

Comment: I included the code.  You'd ask for the HTML, so I provided it from the debugging in the browser.  Hoping someone out there has experience with Telerik controls and can tell me what the window control is adding that I can also take advantage of without having to include the unneeded window on the page.